# Conditionally Copy a Row to Another Workbook based on the name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that will copy a row of information based on a customer name to that customer's corresponding workbook.  For instance, if I have a customer named ABC Industries, I want it to copy that row into the ABC Industries workbook on a new line.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you've tried that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to be generous and assume you do not know where to start.

All the information in this answer could be found by looking through the questions and answers of the last two or three months.  There is much relevant information on this site particularly under the tag `excel-vba`.  You will get better answers if you ask small, specific questions that prove you have tried.

What you are proposing is not good practice.  You are duplicating data across multiple workbooks and I **guarantee** the workbooks will soon be hopelessly out of step.

Play with the code below but then think about linking the workbooks so the data is only present once.  I also suspect Access would be a better tool if you want very different views of the same data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub WriteToOtherWorkbook()

  Dim PathCrnt As String
  Dim RowNext As Long
  Dim WBookOther As Workbook
  Dim WBookOtherName As String

  ' I assume all workbooks are in the same folder at the active workbook
  PathCrnt = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

  If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    ' It is easy to get into a muddle if there are multiple workbooks
    ' open at the start of a macro like this.  Avoid the problem until
    ' you understand it.
    Call MsgBox("Please close all other workbooks", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' I assume you know how to find the name of the relevant workbook.
  WBookOtherName = "ABC Industries.xls"

  ' Open the named workbook      
  Set WBookOther = Workbooks.Open(PathCrnt & "\" & WBookOtherName)
  With WBookOther
    ' I assume you have some system for naming the sheets in the
    ' company workbooks.
    With .Sheets("XXXXXX")

      ' If you know that the last row will have a value in, for example,
      ' column "B" use this code which is the equivalent of going to
      ' the bottom of column "B", clicking Ctrl+Up to find the last
      ' cell with a value and then adding one to that value.
      RowNext = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

      ' If you are not sure which column of the last row is
      ' guaranteed to contain a value, use this code.
      RowNext = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

      ' Write some values to the row
      .Cells(RowNext, 1) = "A"
      .Cells(RowNext, 2) = "B"

    End With
    .Save       ' Save the changes
    .Close      ' Close the workbook
    Set WBookOther = Nothing    ' Clear reference to workbook
  End With

End Sub
```

This code works through the worksheets looking for a particular name.

```
For InxWS = 1 To Worksheets.Count
  If Worksheets(InxWS).Name = "ABC Industries" Then
    Found = True
    Exit For
  EndIf
Next

If Found Then
  With Worksheets(InxWS)
    ' Add data
  End With
Else
  Call MsgBox("No worksheet for AC Industries",vbYesOK)
Endif
```

I hope this is enough to get you started.  AS I said at the beginning, you need to be a lot more specific before any one can offer more than general help.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I actually actually used the wrong wording.  I am trying to get the information into the appropriate customer worksheet, not workbook.

Comment: Duplicating data is not a good idea where ever you put it.  It is so easy for someone to update one copy and not the other.  I hope you do not have many customers.  I have worked with workbooks with 40 worksheets and they are very difficult to navigate.  I believe the theoretical limit is 255 worksheets per workbook.  I have left my original code alone and added some code for finding worksheets.